# How can I subset a list in r by extracting the elements that contain a string?

Tags: r, subset

I have a list:

```
mylist<-list()
data<-1:162
listlabel<-c("a","bpt","b","fpt")
for (i in 1:4){
label<-listlabel[i]
mylist[[label]]<-data
}
```

I want to create a new list from the elements in my list that contain a certain string: in this case 'pt'. My new list should contain the elements 'bpt' and 'fpt'.

I thought 'grep' would do it, but when I try it, it returns an empty list.

```
newlist<-list(grep("pt",mylist))
```

How can I create the new list keeping only the selected elements containing my string?

Comment: The input list `mylist` could be defined like this: `Map(function(x) 1:162, c("a", "bpt", "b", "fpt"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` should be on the `names` and not the values of the `list`

```
mylist_sub <- mylist[grep('pt', names(mylist))]
```

Comment: Will this still work if I try to look for two strings at the same time? i.e. `mylist_sub <- mylist[grep(c('pt','a'), names(mylist))]`? I tried it and I get the error:`argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @matlabcat the pattern is not vectorized.  You need `grep('pt|a', names(mylist))`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering one more thing..is there a way to get the remaining elements of the list? Sort of `grep(!'pt|a', names(mylist))`? i.e. not the elements in quotes, but all the others?

Comment: @matlabcat you need `grep('pt|a', names(mylist), invert = TRUE)` or use `!grepl("pt|a", names(mylist))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `purrr::keep` and `grepl`

```
library(purrr)

mylist %>% keep(grepl('pt', names(mylist)))
```

**output**

```
$bpt
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
 [24]  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46
 [47]  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
 [70]  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92
 [93]  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
[116] 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138
[139] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161
[162] 162

$fpt
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
 [24]  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46
 [47]  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
 [70]  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92
 [93]  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
[116] 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138
[139] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161
[162] 162
```